# XPath for getting nodes from HTML fragment based on element text content

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I need an XPath expressions for the following HTML fragment (DOM structure)

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="product-compare-row">
  <div class="spec-title half-size">Model</div>
 <div class="spec-values half-size">
  <span class="spec-value">kast</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

So I need the `kast` value if the `spec-title` `div` contains `Model`.

I've tried `//div[preceding-sibling::div[contains(.,"Model)")]]` but that doesn't work.

Comment: There's (almost) nothing wrong with your XPath, but as written, both your XPath and your XML will result in errors. Bottom line: `contains(.,"Model)")` must be `contains(.,"Model")`, your XML misses a closing `</div>` and at end of your expression, add `/span/text()`. See [corrected XML and XPath in action at XPathTester.com here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b1af7d4423d2d465fea8c5878a35dace). (PS: the answer given is just as correct, but works the other way around).

Answer (score 4):

The XPath you are looking for is:

```
//div[contains(@class, "spec-title") and contains(text(), "Model")]/following-sibling::div/span/text()
```

It is a little bit tricky to follow, but in plain English:

1. Select all `div` elements who have a class `spec-title` and who have text that contains 'Model'.
2. Find **any** of this `div's` following siblings if they are a `div`.
3. Traverse to any of their children which are a `span` and return their text.

Comment: Hi lambo, Thanks for the response. This does the job! Thanks so much!! Works perfectly!